# Get SOAP response to xml

Tags: php, xml, soap

Stack Overflow is full with questions like this, I'm aware of that. But none of the questions and accepted answers have solved it for me.

I'm getting a SOAP response like this:

```
string(402482) "ZSDSD1BKA00_DE_02DE00010000001083212550JVBERi0xLjUNJeLjz9MNCjExNCAwIG9iag08PC9MaW5lYXJpemVkIDEvTCAxMDgzMjEvTyAxMTYv RSAxODY2Mi9OIDEyL1QgMTA3Nzk3L0ggWyA1MDMgMjc2XT4+DWVuZG9iag0gICAgICAgICAgICAg DQoxMzQgMCBvYmoNPDwvRGVjb2RlUGFybXM8PC9Db2x1bW5zIDQvUHJlZGljdG9yIDEyPj4vRmls dGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0lEWzwxREZGRkVGMUM4Q0E0NTI4QjBBMUYxOUEyNTMwREQ2OD48RURD QTlGRDBFNTE4N0M0N0JGRUZCOEM0MjlCRTUwMjE+XS9JbmRleFsxMTQgMzZdL0luZm8gMTEzIDAg Ui9MZW5ndGggOTMvUHJldiAxMDc3OTgvUm9vdCAxMTUgMCBSL1NpemUgMTUwL1R5cGUvWFJlZi9X WzEgMiAxXT4+c3RyZWFtDQpo3mJiZBBgYGJg/g0kGEKABONRIMHiCiSYNEASK0DEG5AEP4i4CZKI ABHiQEJIDyTWDiL+AwmuVhCLDaTDCsQtBHHZgcReIMHIwAiyg4GRIuI/Y9NngAADAOlxDEINCmVu ZHN0cmVhbQ1lbmRvYmoNc3RhcnR4cmVmDQowDQolJUVPRg0KICAgICAgICAgDQoxNDkgMCBvYmoN PDwvRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0kgMjE3L0wgMjAxL0xlbmd0aCAxODcvUyAxNDM+PnN0cmVh bQ0KaN5iYGBgZmBg8mZgZWDg38PAx4AAfEAZVgYWBo6qZQyMDAwCDNf1/NQ/HVzCrMDAO79pAssO rrZJjgW7zB7nbQCqZvMMlpJUbfRmmsaqwzPpwFIQCyjGNI2BvaIBhBoqgIipAkyzAzFW04AG+TMw TgYZKATEwmCHtDPwMn543+ykJGjUpMDleJGnJfMAA3vLf8Y/YRmvWBhtGksgDg5gYJzyEUgDHcvQ A8TBDIxLGCF8RlGAAAMA2bs1zA0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDWVuZG9iag0xMTUgMCBvYmoNPDwvTWV0YWRh dGEgODEgMCBSL1BhZ2VMYWJlbHMgMTA4IDAgUi9QYWdlcyAxMTAgMCBSL1R5cGUvQ2F0YWxvZz4+ DWVuZG9iag0xMTYgMCBvYmoNPDwvQ29udGVudHNbMTE4IDAgUiAxMTkgMCBSIDEyMCAwIFIgMTIx IDAgUiAxMjIgMCBSIDEyMyAwIFIgMTI0IDAgUiAxMjcgMCBSXS9Dcm9wQm94WzAgMCA1OTUuMjIg ODQyXS9NZWRpYUJveFswIDAgNTk1LjIyIDg0Ml0vUGFyZW50IDExMSAwIFIvUmVzb3VyY2VzIDEz NSAwIFIvUm90YXRlIDAvVHlwZS9QYWdlPj4NZW5kb2JqDTExNyAwIG9iag08PC9GaWx0ZXIvRmxh dGVEZWNvZGUvRmlyc3QgMTE3L0xlbmd0aCA5OTUvTiAxNC9UeXBlL09ialN0bT4+c3RyZWFtDQpo 3rxX227bOBD9FT5uHxxeJFISUBhw3LproEmDStgWCPyg2lxHC10MWUHTv+8MKcqSYze+AAuC4MyQ HB6O5owk7knCCPcUETKCMSAiCGEMicdwjIinYPQZkZGEkZMogHW+IJxHOOHBIg8Fn3CJW31JhCfB 7BufaAmI53m4C7xKML9/T6dVXtXxJl1qVLbKQGDkK8ihgQHyeEw/vjSf4iZtcNWnmBtgdmZWlQ0Y k4QzAw/3Jokw0KzsG1BWVgaOlUMDxHp5qKtlrJtH+vBhRhP90tB5ka71dEG/f/nxn17iEfMCzhXS 7J4XSkIYhOo08CyiTgsAIXeaQryi0wRGyp47Hj/S+XR6m271CvYbNAswlSv9ghYbCyJ89GfutgAg Xx7Iv2m+1SDcEU7jSavGd4TdMEGTXxu9ixitNnZ+PIa9k+1Slw0JI06n6eZvna2fGsIZY/SDtlMj wRWd5el6SzzfhPf2tnp5HEl4/iOPQWLAatwSLMzsLC2y/NdfSVboLbnXP8nXqkjLd2buPi00NTMw YewP8V1ipuKm1s3yid5XdZHmxvTNovEBzLxJ82w5Kde5JozGjS7+IWF7M1yKYOts01Q1/d67hLki RhPXHDj4Y7msVlm5pt+yclJus06fZfW2mT6lNfHE3gEm+fHZfU7bJVwIGj//aBBMUj9rg6qDBr5X
```

... but much longer.

Then I use `simplexml_load_string` to convert it, resulting in an apparently empty object. Now I've learned that this object is not empty though. `print_r` and `var_dump` are of no help and I used simplexml_tree.php for help. But I'm now stuck on how I can access a property within the result. I tried a bunch of different variations, most of them left me either a blank page, or an error 500.

This is the response I expect:

[image]

Trying to access property `ORBLK`, like I wrote, with many variations, has not been successful. Thats my current try (resulting a blank page):

```
$resultRow = (string)$xml->children('soap-env', true)->Body->children('n0', true)->Z_SDB_GET_SDB_FOR_MATERIALResponse->T_SDB->item->DOKAR;
```

How would I be able to access the property **ORBLK**?

Comment: have you tried using The SimpleXMLIterator class to convert the XML to an array?

Comment: Would probably work just fine with a regular XML response, but I'm receiving a SOAP response, which is different in the way you handle the output.